# OCaml: find value of specific type

Tags: ocaml, static-typing

I have the list of some values where I need to find out which kind of value is first:

```
type my_types =
    | MAlpha
    | MBeta of int list
    | MGamma of string * int

let find_first where what =
    List.iter ( fun m ->
        | MAlpha ->
            (* iterate frough "what" to find if it was asked to look and return it if it was *)
        | (* do the same for all other types *)
    ) where;
;;

let main =
    let where_to_find = [MGamma, MAlpha, MBeta] in
    let what_to_find = [MAlpha, MBeta] in
    (match (first_found where_to_find what_to_find) with
    | MAlpha ->
        (* should return this *)
    )
;;
```

Is there a way to do so without touching all types of **MyType** within **find_first** - is it possible to compare types of two values?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `List.create`, and why are you giving it two other names?

Comment: @PascalCuoq, fixed that. So, I have **where_to_find** and need to know which type from shown within **what_to_find** is stored firstly within **where_to_find**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to look at this is that you have an equivalence relation for your type; i.e., you have some places where you want to treat all the `MAlpha`s the same, all the `MBeta`s the same, and all the `MGamma`s the same.  A standard handling for equivalence relations is to pick a representative element that represents the whole set of equivalent values (the equivalence class).

In your case you could use `MAlpha` to represent all the `MAlpha`s (but there's only one of them), `MBeta []` to represent all the `MBeta`s and `MGamma ("", 0)` to represent all the `MGamma`s.  You would have a function to calculate the representative value from a given one:

```
let malpha = MAlpha
let mbeta = MBeta []
let mgamma = MGamma ("", 0)

let canonicalize =
    function
    | MAlpha -> malpha
    | MBeta _ -> mbeta
    | MGamma _ -> mgamma

let find_first where what =
    canonicalize (List.find (fun x -> List.mem (canonicalize x) what) where)

let main () =
    let where_to_find = [MGamma ("a", 3); MAlpha; MBeta [3; 4]] in
    let what_to_find = [malpha; mbeta] in
    try
        let found = find_first where_to_find what_to_find
        in
            if found = malpha then (* what to do *)
            else if found = mbeta then (* what to do *)
            else (* what to do *)
    with Not_found -> (* nothing was there *)
```

I have written code like this and it doesn't come out too bad.  In your case it allows you to specify the `what` parameter a little bit naturally.  One downside, though, is that you can't pattern match against `malpha`, `mbeta`, and `mgamma`.  You have to do equality comparisons against them.

It may be that you wanted to find the specific value in the list, rather than the canonicalized value.  I think the changes for that case should be pretty clear.

This also answers the second part of your question.  The `List.find` function will stop as soon as it finds what it's looking for.

OCaml defines an ordering relation for all types that don't contain functional values in them.  If this built-in (polymorphic) ordering doesn't do what you want, you have to define your own.  You would certainly need to do this to compare values of two different types; but that is not what you're doing here.

If there's no element in the list that looks like what you said you wanted, this version of `find_first` will raise the exception `Not_found`.  That's something else to think about.

Comment: That is precisely what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The code you have posted would not compile, but I think you are looking for the following information:

1. It is possible to write so-called or-patterns, as in, for instance, `(function MAlpha | MBeta _ -> ...)`.
2. But patterns are not first-class citizens. You cannot build a pattern from a list (and by the way, `[MGamma, MAlpha, MBeta]` is one of the things that does not compile in your question), nor can you pass a pattern as argument to a function.
3. However, you can build and pass around a function that matches for a pattern, so if you are willing to change your function `find_first` to take a function instead of a list for `what`, it will be more convenient to use.

Comment: I think I did not explained it good enaugh, sorry. It's hard to think in OCaml's terms after C-like languages. I wasn't even able to write compiling example :)